# jQuery empty selector (null selector)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Sometimes it is useful to have an empty jQuery object, to be used either as a default value or as an initial value, when constructing a collection of items.

For an example, see [here](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/499259.aspx).

One way to do it would be to use a selector which is unlikely to match anything, like `$('skdhjfksjdhfksjhdf')`, but this is obviously inelegant.

How can I get an empty jQuery object in elegant style ?

Comment: Where would you need an empty selector?

Comment: Interesting, what's the point?

Comment: What do you mean? Perhaps further explanation and complete sentences would help garner an answer.

Comment: Really not bad enough to warrant two down votes.

Comment: I'm using empty jQuery object when I need to make an operation on an undetermined number of nodes (where zero is an acceptable solution). It can be to add a class on several inputs when validating a form or to filter a list of items.

Answer (score 34):

Starting with jQuery 1.4, a simple `$()` will return an empty set. [jQuery 1.4 release notes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14) ("jQuery() returns an empty set").

For earlier versions, use `$([])`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean...

```
//just get jQuery...
var foo = $();

//or just get the browser using jQuery...
if($.browser.msie){
  alert('You are using the blue e!');
}
```